# UpdateOrCreate on relation not working when updating

Tags: laravel

User.php

```
 public function loginToken()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\LoginToken');
}
```

SomeController.php

```
 protected function generateToken($user)
{
  $user->loginToken->updateOrCreate(['token' => Str::random(40)]);
}
```

login_tokens migration

```
 public function up()
{
    Schema::create('login_tokens', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->foreignId('user_id')->unique();
        $table->string('token');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

Error

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException
>   SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `login_tokens` (`token`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (JwUIE4bPUZ19QppdfKWXYJq5HGPsKUiQubOC0NB7, 2020-06-12 09:41:06, 2020-06-12 09:41:06))

**Create** is working fine but **Update** is giving Error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
$user->loginToken->updateOrCreate(['user_id' => $user->id],['token' => Str::random(40)]);
```

Comment: Your answer worked for me. But I am not sure why user_id needs to be provided when we are already using the relation $user->loginToken. You know what I mean because we do not provide user_id during Create and it works.